# Setting time zone in Moment?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when deploying my app to GCP because it relies heavily on time zone NOW() but sometimes its using a different time zone than my local dev env.
Is it possible to set time zone to LOS angeles so no matter where its deployed that it will use that time zone?

```
moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles')
let endTime = moment(new Date(filteredTimeLeft)).unix();
const convertSec = Number(coin.seconds);
const calcTime = endTime - convertSec - moment().unix();
```

something like this? does this make sense?
thanks

Comment: That's pretty much why UTC exists. It may be better to use UTC throughout and convert with a simple utility function where needed.

Comment: Does this work then?
    let endTime = momentTz(new Date(filteredTimeLeft)).tz('America/Los_Angeles').unix();
    const convertSec = Number(coin.seconds);
    const calcTime = endTime - convertSec - momentTz().tz('America/Los_Angeles').unix();